# I want to schedule data feed on every 24th of month weekday and if 24th comes on weekend then it reschedule to Monday. How i do that?

Tags: archer

I want to schedule data feed on every 24th of month weekday and if 24th comes on weekend then it reschedule to Monday. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This question should not me downgraded. This is a legitimate question.

Option 1: you can trigger data feeds via Archer API. I think that this functionality has been added in Archer v6. Not sure about v5.
In this case you will need to run the code on 24th day of each month that will either trigger the datafeed execution, or will reschedule the execution in case of the weekend.
This is a relatively simple solution that require some coding.

Option 2: you can create another data feed that will execute daily and it will update schedule for the targeted data feed. In this case you will read the date and schedule of the data feed to execute from the Archer Instance database directly and will be making changes to the data feed configuration in Archer Instance database as required via SQL statement embedded into the 2nd datafeed.
This is not simple, but doable if you know SQL and understand Archer table structure.
I have managed to trigger LDAP synch multiple times a day this way.

Good luck!